# Issue with Linq query syntax. Cannot convert to list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am getting an error when trying to convert my linq query to a list like I would normally do.

Here is my query:

```
var Services = (from sa in _ctx.ServiceAttrs
    join pp in _ctx.ProcessorProducts 
        on new { ServiceId = sa.ServiceID, PrsnPk = ActivePrsnPk } equals
        new { ServiceId = pp.ServiceID, PrsnPk = pp.PrsnPK } into tmp
            from PersonServices in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                .Select(PersonServices => new ReviewerServiceDto()
                {
                    ServiceId = sa.ServiceID,
                    ServiceAliasDescription = sa.ServiceAlias,
                    IsSelected = (PersonServices.IsActivated == null) 
                        ? false
                        : true,
                }).OrderBy(dto => dto.ServiceAliasDescription).ToList();
```

I am getting redlined right at the ToList(). Tells me parenthesis can be removed, however when I remove them, it will no longer evoke the method to convert to list...

I thought I was missing a bracket somewhere but It looks good to me.

Comment: If I see it well, the first bracket does not have a closing pair (or can be remove that).

Comment: Is it redlined (error) or greenlined (warning) ?  Post the exact message, including the error/warning number.

Comment: Note also that `IsSelected = (PersonServices.IsActivated == null) 
                        ? false
                        : true` is equivalent to simply `IsSelected = PersonServices.IsActivated != null`.

Comment: If you broke the query up into multiple statements, rather than trying to force the whole thing into a single statement, the problem would either go away, or become apparent to you.  Trying to force the whole query into a single statement is needlessly complicatin git.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It is a redline error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides a missing bracket, you are mixing LINQ syntax with extension method syntax. In `from PersonServices in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty() .Select` the select cannot be an extension method call.

This should work

```
var Services = (
    from sa in _ctx.ServiceAttrs
    join pp in _ctx.ProcessorProducts
        on new { ServiceId = sa.ServiceID, PrsnPk = ActivePrsnPk }
        equals new { ServiceId = pp.ServiceID, PrsnPk = pp.PrsnPK }
        into tmp
    from PersonServices in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new ReviewerServiceDto() {
        ServiceId = sa.ServiceID,
        ServiceAliasDescription = sa.ServiceAlias,
        IsSelected = PersonServices.IsActivated != null
    }
)
.OrderBy(dto => dto.ServiceAliasDescription)
.ToList();
```

A proper indentation helps in distinguishing the LINQ syntax part from the extension method part.

Btw.: the second `from` would have to be expressed as `SelectMany` in extension method syntax.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are opening a bracket without closing it.

You are applying the `OrderBy()` and the `ToList()` to:  `tmp.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(..)`, if you want to do that on purpose, all you need is to add a select after that and close the bracket).

You need to add a select clause to tell what data you require from the query. This [msdn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations) describes the basic query operation and structure.

```
  }).OrderBy(dto => dto.ServiceAliasDescription).ToList()   select something);
```

Comment: This is true, however if I close it, it will not recognize the sa alias. So I am not sure if there is a different way to structure this or not...

Comment: Also, I am needing to select all of it, not just something. My apologizes, I am a novice at linq. This does solve the issue however, but I really just want to shove it all into  a list.